# How to ignore file extensions with one additional character?

Tags: gitignore

I've recently been curious on how to ignore certain extensions, but with exactly one extra character. One example of where this is relevant is in vim if the `.swp` already exists another extension is used, like `.swo`, `.swn`, etc. So for this pattern I'd be interested in `*.sp` plus exactly one character.

I've thought about using `*.sp*` to match this pattern however, I feel like there could be edge cases where this collects something unintended so I would prefer a more focused solution.

So is there a way in a gitignore file to specific any extra character to satisfy the patter above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this link: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Ignoring-Files
You can use `?` to mean one character, so you can do: `*.sp?` and to be more specific, if you have a list of possible value for this one caractere then you can use: `*.sp[abd]` this will ignore .spa, .spb, .spd

Answer (score 2):

If this one character is always present then use `*.sp?`. `?` stands for exactly one character and it also works in Linux shell.